# Javascript won't execute "style.transition"

Tags: javascript

I'am trying to create photo gallery. I've got a problem with this code:

```
function ZmienZdjecie(CurrentObject, NextObject, Direction) {
    var current = document.getElementById(CurrentObject);
    var kierunek = "0%";

    if (Direction == "Next") {
        kierunek = "100%";
    } else {
        kierunek = "-100%";
    }
    current.style.transition = "right 1.0s, opacity 1s";
    current.style.right = kierunek;
    current.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function () { LokPhoto(current) }, 500)
    var next = document.getElementById(NextObject);
    next.style.display = "block";
    next.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";
    next.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

I don't know why Javascript won't execute this line:

```
next.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";
```

Could You tell me what is wrong with this ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the browser does one thing at a time (in most cases), it is for all intents and purposes assigning those styles at the same time.

This means that the `transition` style hasn't actually applied yet when you're also setting the `opacity`, causing it to not take effect.

If you want a style to be affected by the transition, try:

```
next.style.transition = "opacity 1.0s";
requestAnimationFrame(function() {next.style.opacity = 1;});
```

This will make it transition nicely. Note that you may need a polyfill for `requestAnimationFrame`.